# Subtraction accumulator

Tags: ruby

I'm currently following the tutorials over at [RubyMonk](http://www.rubymonk.org), and one of the problems I need to solve is to write a `subtract` function that would meet these conditions:

> - invoking `subtract(4, 5)` should return `-1`
> - invoking `subtract(-10, 2, 3)` should return `-15`
> - invoking `subtract(0, 0, 0, 0, -10)` should return `10`

Coming from a traditional imperative programming background (C, Lua, Java, etc.), my first attempt would have been something like this:

```
def subtract *numbers
  start = numbers[0]
  tail  = numbers.drop(1) 

  for i in tail do
    start -= i
  end

  return start
end
```

But, this just felt wrong in Ruby, and I don't doubt that it is. Trying to use a more Ruby-esque style, I thought it would be better to use some of `Array`'s methods.

Here is my latest version:

```
def subtract *numbers
  (numbers.drop 1).inject(numbers[0]) { |x, y| x-y}
end
```

One thing to note is that this is essentially the same thing as above, I just moved most of the looping into `Array#inject`. To me, simply moving logic isn't a new style per se, and so conceptually this is nothing new to me.

Therefore my questions are:

- Is this true Ruby style? If not, how could I make it so, and how would that new style differ from the current?
- Is there any way to improve readability? ('Cause honestly the current version lacks quite a bit).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some notes:

- `def subtract *numbers`: While Ruby allows to omit parens, the community consensus is that it makes signatures harder to read.
- `(numbers.drop 1)`: When you have to write parens like this, it's a signal that you should just write them in the method call. It looks like Scala or Haskell, not Ruby.
- As @Nakilon pointed out, you can drop the `drop`/`first`, a fold without an initial value takes the first one.
- The identity value for subtraction is `0`, let's use it for empty inputs.
- `xs.inject(initial) { |acc, x| acc.method(x) }` -> `xs.inject(initial, :method)`

We can now write:

```
def subtract(*numbers)
  numbers.inject(0, :-)
end
```

> For me, simply moving logic isn't a new style per se, and so conceptually this is nothing new to me.

I don't agree. The steps followed are conceptually the same, yes, but the use of a widely known generic abstraction like `reduce`/`inject` has reduced the overall complexity. Of course, one abstraction does not make much difference, but dozens of them change the way a whole program describes what it's doing. And that's what programing is about: building abstractions to reduce complexity.

Comment: Okay thank you for the guidance. :) I agree that abstraction is key. I just felt that perhaps Ruby had a more awesome, totally new, nothing a C programmer could of thought up way of doing it. :P 

_P.S. I actually wanted my Ruby to look like Haskell, but okay, whatever...*shrugs* haha_

Comment: @Miguel. In fact we can write `numbers.inject(0, :-)` as Nakilon suggested. In any case, nothing special about Ruby on this regard, that can be done in any language that supports basic functional programming.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand, why do you need `.first` and `.drop`:

```
def subtract(*numbers)
  numbers.inject{ |acc, x| acc - x }
end
```

Or:

```
def subtract(*numbers)
  numbers.inject :-
end
```

Answer (score 0):

They are NOT the same:
Original: "invoking subtract(4, 5) should return -1"

```
def subtract(*numbers)
  numbers.inject :-
end
subtract(4,5) -> -9
```

How do we get the correct result with nice Ruby code?

Comment: Are you answering or asking? This space is reserved for answering only.